# Does $E(|X_n - X|) \rightarrow 0$ implies $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

I think it does, I've tried proving it by using Chebishev's Inequality but it only prove that it works with quadratic convergence and I can't adapt it... Can you help me please? Thank you very much!

**SOLVED**

Answer (score 3):

$$P(|X_n-X|\geqslant\varepsilon)\leqslant\varepsilon^{-1}E(|X_n-X|)$$

Comment: P.S. Get yourself a textbook!

Comment: I thought I had a good one... But that's not in it...

Comment: Seriously? Then you owe to us to say which textbook it is...

Comment: I'm feeling very stupid right now, of course it is! I'm sorry I asked this question... And thank you for your answer!